# How to run example with simulation package in Java?

Tags: java, simulation, event-simulation

Need help to run examples in the JavaSim simulation package.

**https://github.com/nmcl/JavaSim**

The example Main.java is available at:

`examples/src/main/java/org/javasim/examples/basic`

Screenshot is attached of the error
[image]

Note that I also performed in Eclipse:

Right click on the project folder -> Properties
Choose 'Java Build Path'
Click on 'Sources' tab on top
Click on 'Add Folder' on the right panel
Selected folder examples and apply

Comment: There is a tutorial at the end of the readme script

Comment: Yes I followed that. Got Build success after maven test and maven install. Then I tried running the example in the said folder. Got many errors. Note: I don't know java, so definitely I am doing something wrong

Comment: Can you post the error here ? And which command you are running on which folder etc ? (I mean, edit your question to post it)

Comment: The `examples` project isn't import as maven. I suggest you to remove (not from disk, only in eclipse) the project, then import it as Maven.

Comment: No, you need something like [this](http://prntscr.com/1uniems) : the `src/main/java` included after the `examples` project, which will means the IDE understand it's maven's project. Also, such as said [this](https://github.com/nmcl/JavaSim/tree/master/examples) readme, maybe you can try to just copy the example, and build only this one and not the global that seems to don't include example in his pom

Comment: No problem I understand. I mean take only the `examples` folder. In this one, you have a pom file so it's a maven project. You also have a readme which contains command to run

Comment: Hello @Elikill58 "thanks you, that was exactly what I was looking for and it works very well"...BTW when is your website coming?

Comment: xD no problem. With pleasure !! My website is coming in few month I think. Also, I will make an answer to explain to other people the issue and how to fix it !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(problem solved in comment)

There is two project in one, but they are not linked.

The first and global one have a `pom.xml` file which make the `src/main/java` folder works and editable. It also make it compile.

In your case, you want to use the "examples" project. This one is NOT linked to the main project. I explain:

You can create a project with multiple sub-project with maven. When you are building the main, all sub are also built according to what you put in the `pom.xml` file.

Back to your case, the main don't use the examples as sub-project. So it have to be compilated in a second hand.

If you include the main project, the second will be used as package and not sub-project. Such as you want a new project without the main, you can copy/paste the "examples" folder and use only this one as project.

Now, You can import it in eclipse as Maven project.